# Logical right shift operator in java

Tags: java

I am beginner to java... I have tried very much but could not find the way the following line

**System.out.println (-1>>>1);**

gives 2147483647 ?

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: That's the *bitwise* right shift operator

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't get this line to give the result you expect, or it gives you the result you wrote but you don't understand why?

Comment: Yes i cannot understand the result

Comment: @ahsanawan it doesn't even result in what you wrote. The result is 2147483647, and not 2147483648.

Comment: It is not "much much greater" operator. See here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Yes you are write the result is 2147483647 but how it gives this result...

Answer (score 3):

This is because the [binary representation](http://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/) of `-1` is `11111111111111111111111111111111`. When you perform an unsigned right bit-shift operation (`>>>`) on it it moves all of the bits right by the argument (`1` in this case) and fills in empty spaces on the left with zeros so you get `01111111111111111111111111111111` which is the binary representation of `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647` (not sure where you got 2147483648 from).

Answer (score 1):

`>>>` is the bitwise right-shift operator, with 0 sign extension - in other words, all bits "incoming" from the left are filled with 0s.

-1 is represented by 32 bits which are all 1. When you shift that right by 1 bit with 0 sign extension, you end up with a value which has the 31 bottom bits still 1, but 0 for the top bit (the sign bit), so you end up with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - which is 2147483647, not 2147483648 as your post states.

Or in JLS terms, from [section 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> The value of `n >>>` `s` is `n` right-shifted `s` bit positions with zero-extension, where:
>
> If `n` is positive, then the result is the same as that of `n >> s`.
>
> If `n` is negative and the type of the left-hand operand is int, then the result is equal to that of the expression `(n >> s) + (2 << ~s)`.
>
> If `n` is negative and the type of the left-hand operand is long, then the result is equal to that of the expression `(n >> s) + (2L << ~s)`.

This definition ends up being a bit of a pain to work with - it's easier to just work with the "0 sign extension right-shift" explanation, IMO.

Comment: @JusticeBauer: Please do not use comments to draw attention to completely unrelated other questions.

Comment: you had one of the highest votes, so thought you might have a clue.I don't have any other way to contact people on this site

Comment: @JusticeBauer: That doesn't mean that leaving comments on random questions is the right way to go about things. It's *intentional* that you can't ask specific users for help - instead, you write the best question you can and let those who are willing to help find it.

Comment: I put a bounty on it and still not getting enough attention or responses